take a value of a column based on a condition of a window function

So I need to create a new column with CurrentPrice where I need to put the latest price inside the GROUP based on column DATE.
So I should look at the newest Date of each Group and put the price of that date.
CASE 
   WHEN DATE = MAX(DATE) PARTITION BY (GROUP) THEN SALESPRICE
   ELSE *here i don't know what to write*
END AS CURRENTPRICE


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.v

If you want the latest price, is MAX correct? Can a product's price only rise and not fall? LAST_VALUE seems more appropriate, but we have no sample data or expected results.

Hi, the price can rise and fall as well so based on that i cannot make the condition

So LAST_VALUE seems to be what you want. Based on  your description, I don't see why you need a CASE expression.

The expected result is the column CurrentPrice in Yellow(on the image)

"The expected result is the column CurrentPrice in Yellow(on the image)" Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question. Images are not helpful, and for things like code/errors/data are normally treated as simply not being there, as we cannot use them to help you.

You probably want: first_value(salesprice) over(partition by [group] order by Date DESC). Last_value doesn't work like one wants (usually)

That's because of the default window window frame being RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW, @siggemannen . LAST_VALUE does work as many expect it to "out of the box" if you extend the window frame to be ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING.

Technically, you can do an update-join, but I strongly advise you not to do it:
UPDATE A
SET CurrentPrice = B.SALESPRICE
FROM yourtable A
JOIN (
    SELECT C.SALESPRICE, C.[GROUP]
    FROM yourtable C
    LEFT JOIN yourtable D
    ON C.DATE < D.DATE and
       C.[GROUP] = D.[GROUP]
    WHERE D.GROUP is null
) B
    ON A.[GROUP] = B.[GROUP]

where the subselect finds the latest salesprice of all groups and the outer command joins the to-be-updated A with the corresponding B group and sets CurrentPrice accordingly.
But this is a very bad practice, don't do it. Instead, either create a separate table where you store this, or a view that does the computation on-the-fly, because:

having such a field would waste storage space, as you duplicate value
your table will not be in normal form
with such a change, you create the motherload of errors, as you will now need to keep in mind the repetitive aggregate data whenever you insert/delete/update records


CREATE TABLE SaleTable (group_ nvarchar(10),Date_ date,Id int,Saleprice decimal(10,2),CurrentPrice decimal(10,2))
INSERT INTO SaleTable (group_,Date_,Saleprice,Id,CurrentPrice)
VALUES
('A','2020-01-03',1200.00,1,null),
('A','2022-04-10'   ,1100.00,2,null),
('A','2023-01-08'   ,1700.00,3,null),
('B','2020-07-03'   ,700.00,4,null),
('B','2022-02-05'   ,500.00,5,null),
('B','2024-01-01'   ,1500.00,6,null),
('c','2024-04-04'   ,1900.00,7,null)

WITH CTE
AS
(
    select Id,SalePrice,Date_,Group_, FIRST_VALUE(SalePrice) OVER (partition by Group_ ORDER BY Date_ desc) CurrentPrice 
    FROM SaleTable
)
UPDATE  SaleTable
    SET SaleTable.CurrentPrice=CTE.CurrentPrice
FROM SaleTable
JOIN CTE
ON SaleTable.Id=CTE.Id

